# How to pin Android application to faster cores on devices with multiple processors

Tags: android, performance, multiprocessing, emulation

First, I am sorry for weird question and will try explain it well. I am working on emulator of another operating system for Android. This emulator can start various old games. Emulator does not require constant power during gameplay. For example if I play racing game then sometimes I need full cpus power and if I am in game menu then emulator takes almost nothing. And here is the problem. Many present devices have 8 cpus (mostly 4 slower and 4 faster). At beginning emulated games run fine, but after some time Android switches game thread to slower cores and games are choppy. And yes, emulator needs more power later, but android won't switch it back to faster cpus. What can I do?

Comment: Try to discover why the scheduler takes your fast core. Overheating?

Comment: No, I didn't notice overheating. I think it's because emulator took only few power for a while, so android made decision and switched game thread to slower cpu. I don't know, it's only idea...I try do some tests with temperature